# uint as indices

Tags: c, debugging

> **EDIT:** Originally I had transcribed `i++` not `i--`
>
> The code now is as it was, and the code in the code block compiles and works.

Why, if `unsigned int i;` is used instead of `int i;` in the code snippet below, does using the function result in a segfault?

```
void insertion_sort_int_array(int * const Ints, unsigned int const len) {
     unsigned int pos;
     int key;
     int i;

     for (pos = 1; pos < len; ++pos) {
         key = Ints[pos];
         for (i = (pos - 1); (i >= 0) && Ints[i] > key; i--) {
             Ints[i + 1] = Ints[i];
         }
         Ints[i + 1] = key;
     }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of (i >= 0) if i is unsigned?

Comment: What is the purpose of (i >= 0) regardless? It's always true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insertionSort(array A)
begin
    for x := 1 to length[A]-1 do
    begin
        value := A[x];
        i := x - 1;
        while i >= 0 and A[i] > value do
        begin
            A[i + 1] := A[i];
            i := i - 1;
        end;
        A[i + 1] := value;
    end;
end;
```

The only difference between the standard insertion sort algorithm and your code is that you're incrementing i instead of decrementing. That's your problem. I bet that in the code you're actually compiling and running, you have i-- instead of i++ in the inner loop. That's why the unsigned i makes a difference - it cannot be negative, so the inner loop will never end. Did you copy the code wrong when you posted?

EDIT:

Well, now that you changed the posted code, it all makes sense, right? An unsigned i will simply underflow to INT_MAX when you decrement it past 0, which will cause you to access memory outside of the array bounds.

Comment: Note that (in the spirit of the OP) this code will crash if you use an *unsigned* int for i. When i reaches 0, it will set i:=i-1 which is -1 in a signed int, but a *very large positive number* in an unsigned int, so the loop would never exit (other than by crashing when trying to access memory way outside the array bounds).

Comment: This was the actual piece of psuedocode used to generate the code used in the post.

Answer (score 2):

THe posted code will fail in either case (possibly with a segfault, possibly only corrupting memory).

The inner loop starts at pos-1 and scans **upwards** in memory until some random condition is met - it does not check if it has passed the end of the array, so will run merrily on until it crashes or the end condition happens to be met by the (undefined) contents of the memory it is corrupting.

You probably meant to scan **downwards** in memory (using i-- in the loop), in which case it would fail because the loop will reach 0. Subtracting 1 from 0 gives you a very large positive number in an unsigned, so the loop will never end (i>=0 is always true) and it will access some memory somewhere in the region of Pluto.

Comment: If on the first iteration of the loop, ints[i] is less than or equal to key, then it will exit the loop without doing anything. However, if ints[i] is greater than key, then it will copy it to ints[i+1] and then move i to i+1 for the next iteration, so it will just fill the memory following ints[i] with the value from the first iteration of the loop until it overwrites something important (e.g. on some computers it could run into a stack frame or an I/O address, causing a crash) or (more likely) runs off the end of your physical memory (causing a crash).

Comment: It is a crash waiting to happen, regardless of whether you use int or unsigned-int.

Comment: Its starting value is i=pos-1. As we step through the loop i is then incremented each time (so it will be pos, then pos+1, then pos+2...). The loop will end when "(i >= 0) && Ints[i] > key". That is, the loop will continue until i becomes negative, or until the ith entry in your array is greater than key. Because pos is not mentioned in the end-condition for the loop, pos has no influence on when the loop will end (other than supplying the starting value for i). It looks as though you need to read some more about how for-loops work.

Comment: I think you didn't notice my earlier amendment, and I didn't realise you hadn't noticed. Upshot being: the "end-condition for the (inner) loop" in a wider sense is the outer not running the inner loop once pos has reached the length of the array. "Subtracting 1 from 0 gives you a very large positive number in an unsigned, so the loop will never end (i>=0 is always true) and it will access some memory somewhere in the region of Pluto." ... is probably an eloquent and humourous enough answer in its entirety for a few more rep.

Answer (score 1):

What keeps i+1 within the bounds of your array 'ints'?  It looks like badly formed data in your array will cause you to index into areas of memory which you shouldn't be in.

Comment: @_ande_turner, but 'key' in  'ints[i] > key' is read from your initial array.  It seems a bit dangerous

Answer (score 0):

`i` will [wraparound] causing access beyond the array limits.

 
Importing limits and comparing to `UINT_MAX` instead of the previous `(i >= 0)` fixes the issue:

```
#include <limits.h>

void insertion_sort_int_array(int * const Integers, unsigned int const N)
{
     unsigned int o;
     int target;
     unsigned int i;

     for (o = 1; o < N; o++) {
         target = Integers[o];
         for (i = (o - 1); (i != UINT_MAX) && (Ints[i] > target); i--) {
             Integers[i + 1] = Integers[i];
         }
         Integers[i + 1] = key;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why, if unsigned int i; is used
>   instead of int i; in the code snippet
>   below, does using the function result
>   in a segfault?

Because for `unsigned int i`, `i >= 0` is always true, so your for loop is unlikely to terminate when you want.

You should always be extremely careful when looping backwards (from high to low) if your counter is unsigned.